# Wrap text in td at the second line

Tags: html, css

The things you see in the picture is in table tag. So, this is how table is:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="3">image</td>
  <td>title</td>
  <td>price</td>
  <td>date</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2" colspan="3">content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If you check the picture after Hardc, you see ... because it breaks up when td is ended. But I want text the break up in the second line.

I have this attributes for the td:

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

I couldn't figure out how I can make exactly same thing but for the second line in td.

[image]

Comment: Could you reformulate your question. It's hard to get the idea :/

Comment: I am sorry, I don't get it

Answer (score 0):

Remove text-overflow: ellipsis;

Add:
display: inline-block;
or
display: block;

PLAY WITH IT!